# Measure time to complete individual streaming steps?

Tags: java, time, java-stream

Is there a library that allows measuring Java Stream steps?

As in "when consuming this stream, X amount of time is spent in that filter, Y amount of time is spent in this map, etc..."?

Or do I have to tinker around a bit?

Comment: Why do you ask? A profiler will profile streams just like any other code, but if you're trying to specifically profile a stream I'd be interested in hearing the reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, there is no 'between' time for steps. The method chain that you define only defines the steps to take (the methods build an internal structure containing the steps).

Once you call the terminal operator, all steps are executed in indeterminate order. If you never call a terminal operator, no steps are executed either.

What I mean by indeterminate order is this:

```
intstream.peek(operation1).peek(operation2).sum();
```

You don't know if `operation1` is called, then `operation2` called, then `operation1` again, or if `operation1` is called a bunch of times, then `operation2` a bunch of times, or something else yet. (I hope I'm correct in saying this. [edit] [correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47946458/1052284)) It's probably up to the implementation of the VM to trade off storage with time complexity.

The best you can to is measure the time each operation takes as you have full control over every operation. The time the stream engine takes is hard to gauge. However, know that when you do this, you're breaking the stream API requirement that operations should be side-effect-free. So don't use it in production code.

Answer (score 0):

The only tool I can think of is [JMH](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/), which is a general benchmarking tool for Java. However note that it might be hard to understand the effect that different `Stream` operators have on the benchmark due to JIT. The fact that your code contains a `Stream` with a bunch of different operators doesn't mean that's exactly the way JIT compiles it.